# Android fetch nearest locations or addresses of on google map according to a gps location

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to fetch locations or addresses of nearest location of a current gps location to show on google map.Currently i am able to show some locaions on map but that are hardcoded i need to fetch all nearest location before drawing the map.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Where are these locations stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way, that how can you achieve it.

```
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Double l1 = location.getLatitude();
            Double l2 = location.getLongitude();
            address = GetAddress(l1, l2);               
        }
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);  

private String GetAddress(Double lat, Double lon) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
    String ret = "";
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
        if (!addresses.equals(null)) {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnedAddress
                        .append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                                "\n");
            }
            ret = "Around: " + strReturnedAddress.toString();
        } else {
            ret = "No Address returned!";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ret = "Location: https://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&q=" + lat
                + "," + lon;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ret = lat + "," + lon;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And also add these permissions in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Thanks Harpreet, from the above code we can find the address of current latitude, longitute but my task is to fine nearest locations of any location like i got a location now what would be nearest locations of a like b,c,d.

Comment: @ricintech: you can see the code snippet `Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);`. I am just taking the first address being provided by google, you can check the list's length first and can show all available addresses, if you want to fetch address of any location provided by user then for this code u first need to get out its lat & lon and the put it in this code.

Comment: This code is doing bad things of network call on main thread.

Answer (score 1):

First get your current location `Lattitude & Longitude`, then get Lattitude & Longitude of each locations you have and find out distance of each place from your current location using [distanceTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) method of Location class and after that find out least distance from your list.

Comment: Thanks Nirav for quick reply but i don't have predefined locations i need to fetch nearest location on the basis of one location i have.